# Good upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^N a^{-n} n^{-b}$, for $a, b \in (0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a, b \in (0, 1]$ and define $S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N a^{-n} n^{-b}$.

## Question

What is a good upper bound for $S_N$ ?

## Observations

By a simple (and probably careless) application of Cauchy-Schwarz, one can already get

$$
S_N \le (\max_{n=1}^N a^{-n})\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-b} \le \frac{1}{a}\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-b}(N^{1-b}-b),&\mbox{ if }0 \le b < 1\\ 
\log(N) + 1,&\mbox{ if }b=1.
\end{cases}
$$
See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328739/bounds-for-sum-t-1tn-ts-t-alpha-mus-t-where-n-ts-sum-1-le) for details.

I was wondering whether one can do much better than this, and using what kind of tools.

---

## Edit

One of the users have suggested trying to look around incomplete gamma functions. Indeed, according to wolfram alpha,
$$\int_{1}^{N} a^{-t}t^{-b}dt = \log^{b-1}(a)\left(\Gamma(1-b,\log(a))-\Gamma(1-b,N\log(a))\right),
$$
where $\Gamma(1-a,x)$ defines an incomplete gamma function.

I'm wondering whether there are any upper bounds for such an expression.

Comment: A quick thought is that we can bound the sum by it's integral approximation, which is now the well-known function called *incomplete gamma function*.

Comment: Ah, ya I thought of exponential integrals, but quickly un-thought the idea again, as I imagined it would lead to really unfriendly expressions...

Comment: I agree that invoking 'incomplete gamma function' itself is nothing but a tautology, giving a fancy name to some unknown expression. However, the catch is that this function is rather well-studied, so we may benefit from existing literature. On the other hand, I suspect that the integral bound itself can be helpful for extracting asymptotic form (which is often done by a careful application of integration by parts), although I have no enough time to pursue this direction right now :s

Comment: Behold, this paper https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01847480/document is a tutorial on how to workout upper bounds on sums using exponential integration  (Ei functional). I should be able to squeeze something out of it.

Comment: @SangchulLee I can write the corresponding integral via incomplete gamma functions. See edited post. Now wondering if the so-obtained expression can be bound. Thanks.

Comment: Something seems weird as $0<a<1$ means $a^{-1}=c>1$, so the sum is exponential in $c$ and is dominated by the last term which is $\frac{c^N}{N^b}$

Comment: If you're saying that the sum diverges in the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$, this is not a problem.

Comment: If you prefer, bound $a^NS_N$ instead.